# Convert data into JSON object

Tags: flutter, dart

How to convert this data into JSON object?
I am trying to convert then i am getting error for jsonDecode and json.decode.

```
[{key: persist:auth-cred, value: {"user":"{\"image\":[\"public/images/branch/1664746288495-65170.jpg\",\"public/images/branch/1664747603436-15997.jpg\"],\"holiday\":\"0\",\"country\":\"India\",\"business_segment\":[{\"value\":\"ab3af5ec-b83a-4918-9be3-d7ac98e24c1f\",\"label\":\"Salons\"},{\"value\":\"1b1def14-3fa2-4799-b118-ce83b66ab72d\",\"label\":\"Skin Care Clinics\"}],\"taxSlab\":18,\"avg_rating\":4.9,\"isActive\":true,\"_id\":\"633a03310705114b4e232c9e\",\"name\":\"The Vega Salon\",\"phone\":\"7062559946\",\"email\":\"abhivjvm@lancersglobal.com\",\"password\":\"$2b$10$p8h6VLgZEjKrE9u8J8UFl.s8JdE0Wghpw/Z4ajcqe8JP.8fQxzci.\",\"gender\":\"unisex\",\"address_line1\":\"Rose Street\",\"address_line2\":\"Malviya Nagar\",\"city\":\"Jaipur\",\"zipcode\":\"302011\",\"website\":\"\",\"gmap\":\"SDC Building, 38-39, Pradhan Marg, Mauji Colony, Moji Nagar, Malviya Nagar, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302017, India\",\"description\":\"Perfect salon for both men and women. Making the best day of your life the most memorable one is a promise extended by us. Our dedicated staff understands the importance of readying you to look your best on your big day. Ensuring the perfect look that compliments both your attire and the wedding theme offering you the best bridal & groom makeup package is our specialty. Whether you want to sport the classic chic look or a vintage boho, we ensure you look pretty n picture perfect and at the centre of everyone’s world.\",\"startTime\":\"2022-10-03T04:30:00.000Z\",\"endTime\":\"2022-10-03T16:30:00.000Z\",\"taxNo\":\"08AARHF1382D1S5\",\"latitude\":26.8592831,\"longitude\":75.80840859999999,\"logo\":\"public/images/branch/1669967198797-79350.jpg\",\"state\":\"NA\",\"countryCode\":91,\"uuid\":\"957672ff-51f7-4528-96ed-84df0ef724d9\",\"businessUuid\":\"949001e9-5ae1-488d-9115-d9405b8021ed\",\"__v\":0,\"otherContact\":\"\",\"id\":\"633a03310705114b4e232c9e\",\"businessCalenderType\":\"shift\"}","authenticated":"true","token":"\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzM2EwMzMxMDcwNTExNGI0ZTIzMmM5ZSIsImlhdCI6MTY5NzYxMTk3OSwiZXhwIjoxNzAwMjAzOTc5fQ.sDsVKyoODAtl6LLqnLyWcJ6x9VwskXsQGcPIq-Vq6fU\"","role":"\"branch\"","_persist":"{\"version\":-1,\"rehydrated\":true}"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the JSON decode will be failing is due to the JSON you're providing being invalid JSON. You need to correctly provide quotes around the key and value, and you also have some escape characters in the JSON content also as I'll highlight below.

If the escape characters should be there, the final JSON should look like this;

```
[{key: "persist:auth-cred", value: {"user":"{\"image\":[\"public/images/branch/1664746288495-65170.jpg\",\"public/images/branch/1664747603436-15997.jpg\"],\"holiday\":\"0\",\"country\":\"India\",\"business_segment\":[{\"value\":\"ab3af5ec-b83a-4918-9be3-d7ac98e24c1f\",\"label\":\"Salons\"},{\"value\":\"1b1def14-3fa2-4799-b118-ce83b66ab72d\",\"label\":\"Skin Care Clinics\"}],\"taxSlab\":18,\"avg_rating\":4.9,\"isActive\":true,\"_id\":\"633a03310705114b4e232c9e\",\"name\":\"The Vega Salon\",\"phone\":\"7062559946\",\"email\":\"abhivjvm@lancersglobal.com\",\"password\":\"$2b$10$p8h6VLgZEjKrE9u8J8UFl.s8JdE0Wghpw/Z4ajcqe8JP.8fQxzci.\",\"gender\":\"unisex\",\"address_line1\":\"Rose Street\",\"address_line2\":\"Malviya Nagar\",\"city\":\"Jaipur\",\"zipcode\":\"302011\",\"website\":\"\",\"gmap\":\"SDC Building, 38-39, Pradhan Marg, Mauji Colony, Moji Nagar, Malviya Nagar, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302017, India\",\"description\":\"Perfect salon for both men and women. Making the best day of your life the most memorable one is a promise extended by us. Our dedicated staff understands the importance of readying you to look your best on your big day. Ensuring the perfect look that compliments both your attire and the wedding theme offering you the best bridal & groom makeup package is our specialty. Whether you want to sport the classic chic look or a vintage boho, we ensure you look pretty n picture perfect and at the centre of everyone’s world.\",\"startTime\":\"2022-10-03T04:30:00.000Z\",\"endTime\":\"2022-10-03T16:30:00.000Z\",\"taxNo\":\"08AARHF1382D1S5\",\"latitude\":26.8592831,\"longitude\":75.80840859999999,\"logo\":\"public/images/branch/1669967198797-79350.jpg\",\"state\":\"NA\",\"countryCode\":91,\"uuid\":\"957672ff-51f7-4528-96ed-84df0ef724d9\",\"businessUuid\":\"949001e9-5ae1-488d-9115-d9405b8021ed\",\"__v\":0,\"otherContact\":\"\",\"id\":\"633a03310705114b4e232c9e\",\"businessCalenderType\":\"shift\"}","authenticated":"true","token":"\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzM2EwMzMxMDcwNTExNGI0ZTIzMmM5ZSIsImlhdCI6MTY5NzYxMTk3OSwiZXhwIjoxNzAwMjAzOTc5fQ.sDsVKyoODAtl6LLqnLyWcJ6x9VwskXsQGcPIq-Vq6fU\"","role":"\"branch\"","_persist":"{\"version\":-1,\"rehydrated\":true}"}}]
```

Otherwise your JSON should look like this to be a truly acceptable JSON format;

```
[{"key":"persist:auth-cred","value":{"user":{"image":["public/images/branch/1664746288495-65170.jpg","public/images/branch/1664747603436-15997.jpg"],"holiday":"0","country":"India","business_segment":[{"value":"ab3af5ec-b83a-4918-9be3-d7ac98e24c1f","label":"Salons"},{"value":"1b1def14-3fa2-4799-b118-ce83b66ab72d","label":"Skin Care Clinics"}],"taxSlab":18,"avg_rating":4.9,"isActive":true,"_id":"633a03310705114b4e232c9e","name":"The Vega Salon","phone":"7062559946","email":"abhivjvm@lancersglobal.com","password":"$2b$10$p8h6VLgZEjKrE9u8J8UFl.s8JdE0Wghpw/Z4ajcqe8JP.8fQxzci.","gender":"unisex","address_line1":"Rose Street","address_line2":"Malviya Nagar","city":"Jaipur","zipcode":"302011","website":"","gmap":"SDC Building, 38-39, Pradhan Marg, Mauji Colony, Moji Nagar, Malviya Nagar, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302017, India","description":"Perfect salon for both men and women. Making the best day of your life the most memorable one is a promise extended by us. Our dedicated staff understands the importance of readying you to look your best on your big day. Ensuring the perfect look that compliments both your attire and the wedding theme offering you the best bridal & groom makeup package is our specialty. Whether you want to sport the classic chic look or a vintage boho, we ensure you look pretty n picture perfect and at the centre of everyone’s world.","startTime":"2022-10-03T04:30:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-10-03T16:30:00.000Z","taxNo":"08AARHF1382D1S5","latitude":26.8592831,"longitude":75.80840859999999,"logo":"public/images/branch/1669967198797-79350.jpg","state":"NA","countryCode":91,"uuid":"957672ff-51f7-4528-96ed-84df0ef724d9","businessUuid":"949001e9-5ae1-488d-9115-d9405b8021ed","__v":0,"otherContact":"","id":"633a03310705114b4e232c9e","businessCalenderType":"shift"},"authenticated":true,"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzM2EwMzMx10adfadfad0e5b11f"}}]
```

Key notes are;

- [{"key":persist:auth-cred, was changed to [{"key":"persist:auth-cred", - this provides valid quotation marks around the key.
- Escape characters (\") were changed to quotation marks also to ensure that they are valid.

Comment: so how to I  made  like this ```[{"key":"persist:auth-cred","value":{"user":{"image":["public/images/branch/1664746288495-65170.jpg","public/images/branch/1664747603436-15997.jpg"],"holiday":"0","country":"India","business_segment":[{"value":"ab3af5ec-b83a-4918-9be3-d7ac98e24c1f","label":"Salons"},```

Comment: Of course. To assist, are you able to give some information about how you're generating your JSON in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the `value` data as `String` and Put an `r` in front of the string literal.

It's Like :

```
var valueData = r"""{"user":"{\"image\":[\"public/images/branch/1664746288495-65170.jpg\",\"public/images/branch/1664747603436-15997.jpg\"],\"holiday\":\"0\",\"country\":\"India\",\"business_segment\":[{\"value\":\"ab3af5ec-b83a-4918-9be3-d7ac98e24c1f\",\"label\":\"Salons\"},{\"value\":\"1b1def14-3fa2-4799-b118-ce83b66ab72d\",\"label\":\"Skin Care Clinics\"}],\"taxSlab\":18,\"avg_rating\":4.9,\"isActive\":true,\"_id\":\"633a03310705114b4e232c9e\",\"name\":\"The Vega Salon\",\"phone\":\"7062559946\",\"email\":\"abhivjvm@lancersglobal.com\",\"password\":\"p8h6VLgZEjKrE9u8J8UFl.s8JdE0Wghpw/Z4ajcqe8JP.8fQxzci.\",\"gender\":\"unisex\",\"address_line1\":\"Rose Street\",\"address_line2\":\"Malviya Nagar\",\"city\":\"Jaipur\",\"zipcode\":\"302011\",\"website\":\"\",\"gmap\":\"SDC Building, 38-39, Pradhan Marg, Mauji Colony, Moji Nagar, Malviya Nagar, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302017, India\",\"description\":\"Perfect salon for both men and women. Making the best day of your life the most memorable one is a promise extended by us. Our dedicated staff understands the importance of readying you to look your best on your big day. Ensuring the perfect look that compliments both your attire and the wedding theme offering you the best bridal & groom makeup package is our specialty. Whether you want to sport the classic chic look or a vintage boho, we ensure you look pretty n picture perfect and at the centre of everyone’s world.\",\"startTime\":\"2022-10-03T04:30:00.000Z\",\"endTime\":\"2022-10-03T16:30:00.000Z\",\"taxNo\":\"08AARHF1382D1S5\",\"latitude\":26.8592831,\"longitude\":75.80840859999999,\"logo\":\"public/images/branch/1669967198797-79350.jpg\",\"state\":\"NA\",\"countryCode\":91,\"uuid\":\"957672ff-51f7-4528-96ed-84df0ef724d9\",\"businessUuid\":\"949001e9-5ae1-488d-9115-d9405b8021ed\",\"__v\":0,\"otherContact\":\"\",\"id\":\"633a03310705114b4e232c9e\",\"businessCalenderType\":\"shift\"}","authenticated": "true","token":"\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzM2EwMzMxMDcwNTExNGI0ZTIzMmM5ZSIsImlhdCI6MTY5NzYxMTk3OSwiZXhwIjoxNzAwMjAzOTc5fQ.sDsVKyoODAtl6LLqnLyWcJ6x9VwskXsQGcPIq-Vq6fU\"","role": "\"branch\"","_persist": "{\"version\":-1,\"rehydrated\":true}"}""";

OR

var valueData = r'' + YourObject.value.toString();

OR

var valueData = r'' + YourObject['value'].toString();
```

After that decode the data like :

```
var decodedData = json.decode(valueData);
print(decodedData['user']);

// You can show the decodedData['user'] consol log like below : 
{"image":["public/images/branch/1664...
```

Then after again the decoded data like below to get the other parameters for ex: `image` :

```
var data = json.decode(decodedData['user']);
print(data['image'].first);

// You can show the data['image'].first consol log like below :
public/images/branch/1664746288495-65170.jpg
```

I hope this solution might be work for you.